# MySQL IF..ELSE with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have a query

```
SELECT IF((select COUNT(*) from produkty where name='ASROCK 760GM-GS3' and id_nokaut='7507601876693181035' and found ='0')=0, (insert into produkty (
         id_nokaut,
         name,
         shop_count,
         offer_count,
         price_min,
         price_max,
         price_avg,
         url,
         opis,
         socket,
         typ_pamieci,
         co,
         image_mini,
         image_medium,
         image_large,
         rate,
         thumbnail,
         image,
         found)
         values(
         '7507601876693181035',
         'ASROCK 760GM-GS3',
         '4',
         '4',
         '171,31',
         '195,00',
         '179,88',
         'http://www.nokaut.pl/plyty-glowne/asrock-760gm-gs3.html',
         'ASRock 760GM-GS3... ',
         'false',
         'false',
         'plyta',
         'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc90x90/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg',
         'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc130x130/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg',
         'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc500x500/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg',
         '0.00',
         'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc90x90/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg',
         'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc130x130/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg',
         '1')), (update produkty set  id_nokaut = '7507601876693181035', shop_count = '4', offer_count = '4', price_min = '171,31', price_max = '195,00', price_avg = '179,88', url = 'http://www.nokaut.pl/plyty-glowne/asrock-760gm-gs3.html', opis = 'ASRock 760GM-GS3... ',  socket = 'false', typ_pamieci = 'false', co = 'plyta', image_mini = 'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc90x90/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg', image_medium = 'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc130x130/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg', image_large = 'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc500x500/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg', rate = '0.00', thumbnail = 'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc90x90/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg', image = 'http://nokautimg1.pl/p-da-99-da99e9e7b3eaebef049d1234fc5c15dc130x130/asrock-760gm-gs3.jpg', found = '1' where  name = 'ASROCK 760GM-GS3'));
```

I'm trying to execute it in MySQL but it gives mi error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
>   nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
>   ear 'into produkty (
>                id_nokaut,
>                name,
>                shop_cou' at line 1

I can't figure out what is wrong, can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're going a very difficult way about doing [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) or [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  However, if you **must** use `IF`, then you want MySQL's [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) - which does not form part of a `SELECT` command - rather than the [`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) that you're currently using (I know, it's confusing!).

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT
INTO    produkty (id_nokaut, name, ...)
VALUES  ('7507601876693181035', 'ASROCK 760GM-GS3', ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
        shop_count = VALUES(shop_count),
        offer_count = VALUES(offer_count),
        ...
```

Comment: OP may need a way to update multiple rows and insert when none is found, this approach is valid only for a single row.

Comment: @piotrm: `id` usually implies a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @piotrm: it's a target column in the `UPDATE`. The query would fail if multiple records satisfied the filter.

Comment: The way count(*) and update is used suggests its a foreign key to some other table.

Comment: @piotrm: it's possible but hardly feasible. Don't think a table can be that denormalized.